# Can not find reference 'NSWorkspace' in '_init_.py'

Tags: appkit, pyobjc, nsworkspace

`from AppKit import NSWorkspace`
I am trying to import NSWorkspace from the AppKit but getting error as unable to find reference. I am using python 3.12 with pyobjc version 10.0

Expecting it should work as I am using it in `activeAppName = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activeApplication()['NSApplicationName']` but since it is not accessible I am not sure whether it is working.

Comment: NSWorkspace, apologies for typo

Comment: Works ok on my system (MacOS Sonoma 14.4) if I delete the code in square brackets, ie ['NSApplicationName'].

Comment: Yes it is working even though showing error as mentioned.

Comment: How did you install Python? What version of macOS, arm64 or x86_64?

Also: What exactly doesn't work and what error do you get? The import works for me, as does the other statement you mention.